# Javascript giving different values in dreamweaver/IE and chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dreamweaver

So, here's what happens.
I was trying to get this to work ([jQuery working in dreamweaver but not in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652595/jquery-working-in-dreamweaver-but-not-in-browser/28656008#28656008)), so I was checking all the command lines at a time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav ul ul").each(function () {
        var navWidth = $(this).width();
        var liWidth = $(this).closest("li").width();
        var gaps = navWidth - liWidth; 
        alert(gaps);
    });
});
```

After using this code, I realised that it gives me different values. Like, in dreamweaver I would get 25, -86 and -163,  but in chrome, I get 54, -34 and -88.

What can I do?

Comment: Your going to have all sorts of issues with that because browsers don't render fonts the same...which means you will slightly different sizes depending on user. You might want to predefine the gap using em, and that way it will at least stay consistent to how it was rendered.